# sending multiple parameters to << operator

Tags: c++

I saw this example of the Eigen library :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
  Matrix2d a;
  a << 1, 2,
       3, 4;
  MatrixXd b(2,2);
  b << 2, 3,
       1, 4;
  std::cout << "a + b =\n" << a + b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a - b =\n" << a - b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Doing a += b;" << std::endl;
  a += b;
  std::cout << "Now a =\n" << a << std::endl;
  Vector3d v(1,2,3);
  Vector3d w(1,0,0);
  std::cout << "-v + w - v =\n" << -v + w - v << std::endl;
}
```

And this part is puzzling me :

```
a << 1, 2,
     3, 4;
```

How can we overload << operator to send multiple parameters like in the example ?

PS : I've already seen this question [C++ overloading << operator multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460079/c-overloading-operator-multiple-parameters)

Comment: I assume it overloads the comma operator. Eek!

Comment: An overloaded comma operator applies?

Comment: Which part of the answers on that page didn't you get?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit On that page they explain this cannot be done, and here the OP is showing something they found that does it.

Comment: I believe that would be https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/CommaInitializer.h.

Comment: I didn't know that the comma operator can be overloaded... (the dot one cannot isn't it ?)

Comment: @Aminos Almost any operators can be overloaded in c++.

Comment: what's a definition of operator ? the sign "?" can be overloaded for example ? and no, not all the operators can be overloaded, the "::" cannot, I read it somewhere.

Comment: @GSerg: Huh? Rici's answer gives two ways to do it, including a proxy type, which is the way Eigen is doing it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But Rici then says *You can then call that as `anyvar << arg1 << arg2`* while what the OP wanted was `anyvar << arg1, arg2`, and regarding that Rici says *No, that is not possible*.

Comment: @GSerg You're only reading the first line of Rici's answer. You have to read the rest of it as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I really can't see what I'm missing. The call of the form `anyvar << arg1, arg2` is only mentioned in the Rici's answer as "No, that is not possible", and the need to overload the comma operator is not mentioned in the answer either, which would be a requirement for making `anyvar << arg1, arg2` possible. Things that are mentioned as possible are `anyvar << std::make_pair(a1, a2)` and `anyvar << arg1 << arg2`.

Comment: @GSerg: You can implement the proxy class approach with any operator you like, including `operator,`... The phrase "no, that is not possible" answers the question "if we can give two or more parameters to an overload of operator <<", to which it is the correct answer.